# Does this exponential have an identity in trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was wondering if there existed any identity that took

\begin{align} e^{a+bi} - e^{-a-bi}
\end{align}

to some combination of trig and hyperbolic trig functions. I can see that you could get to

\begin{align}
e^a(\cos(b)+i\sin(b)) - e^{-a}(\cos(b)-i\sin(b))
\end{align}
But I am wondering if there is someway to get the exponentials that are left here so that it is all in trig and hyperbolic trig form. I cannot seem to find any identity that fits this bill, but was wondering if I am missing something here.

Thank you!

Comment: $e^a\cos(b) - e^{-a}\cos(b) =2\sinh(a) \cos(b)$

Comment: @Henry Thank you. Not sure why I couldn't figure out how to pull them apart like that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: set $$z=a+bi$$   
$$2\cdot cosh\left(z\right)$$   
which you can expand.    
https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.35.E35     
I could write it out for this particular case but DLMF is much more thorough.

Comment: Don't these two answers contradict? The one given by @Henry seems to result in $sinh(a)cos(b) + icosh(a)sin(b)$, but if you look at it the way you did, it seems to give you $cosh(a)cos(b) + isinh(a)sin(b)$. All of these multiplied by $2$ of course. Am I still missing something here?

Comment: Ah I think I see. It should be \begin{align} 2 \cdot sinh(z) \end{align} This seems to then agree with the other answer. Thanks to you both!